# H10 "App Crashed" Error deploying Streamlit App with Heroku

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, heroku-cli, streamlit

I'm trying to deploy a Streamlit app with Heroku. I followed [these](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-deploy-a-streamlit-app-with-heroku-5f76a809ec2e) instructions, but when I run the 'heroku open' command, the app tells me to check my logs. When I do, it says I have an H10 error. I have made sure that I am not manually creating a port which seems to be the standard source of this issue. Any debugging suggestions are much appreciated.

I have:

Procfile:

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
streamlit==0.60.0
```

setup.sh:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/
echo “\
[general]\n\
email = \”<myemail@domain>\”\n\
“ > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml
echo “\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
“ > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

Comment: I resolved by switching to SSH authentication, still unsure what the bug was.

Comment: How to switch to SSH authentication. I mean what changes to be made in setup.sh?

Comment: @Prateek I followed this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) to set up ssh for my app. I think it is about the `create` command rather than setup.sh